# dynamic drop down

Tags: java

i want to display a drop down dynamically that is the values should be from database,i have the list holding the values,how would i use it now ?

Comment: What are you developing? A web site? A standalone program?A script?

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on what class you are using for your drop down UI. It must take its options from somewhere, read the documentation, identify the format it takes the options, and write code to munge your list into that format.

Comment: i am using java +html select to populate

Comment: Then you just need to generate option elements ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6 ). A loop through your list in whatever templating language you are using is probably the way forward.

Comment: can anyone explain with example 
<select name="List">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2"> 2</option>
  
</select>
replace the values 1 and 2 reading it from database ,considering i have the list read,how do i loop it ?